# What is the Computational Complexity of this Difference of Squares problem?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Consider a quadratic function over positive integers. For example say a simple function of the form: $f(n)=3n+4n^2$

Now given any positive integer $C$ find two integers such that: $f(i)-f(j) = C$

What is the complexity of such problems? I tried searching for a bit but didn't find an answer..

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your post to describe the motivation/context and why this will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach. With $f(n) = an + bn^2$ we have, $C = (i-j)(a + b(i+j))$. Given any $C$, find a factor of it. Let $C = \alpha\beta$ with $\alpha \le \beta$. Now we have to solve for $i - j = \alpha$ and $a + b(i+j) = \beta$. Given any $C$ we have to only enumerate upto $\sqrt{C}$ to get all integral factorizations. Once we have a factorization we can solve the equations to test where integral solution exists. We iterate from 1 upto $\sqrt{C}$ an in each iteration we do some constant number of division operations which again would be of order at most $\sqrt{C}$. Thus overall complexity is $O(C)$.